# Nifi Flowfile Progress

Tags: http, apache-nifi

I'm trying to figure out what one could do to see where a flowfile is at in a nifi flow over http. For example, say I have a webpage where a user could upload files. I want to indicate to the user that that file is currently being ingested/processed, and possibly what stage its at. What does nifi offer that I could leverage to get this information? Like is there a way to see which processors a flowfile has gone through, or the processor/queue it's currently in?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to use NiFi's provenance events and issue a provenance query for the flow file UUID to see all the current events which should give you a graph of all the processors it has passed through:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#data_provenance

You can open Chrome Dev Tools while using provenance features in the UI and see what calls are being made to the REST API.

Another option is to build in some kind of status updates into your flow. You could stand up your own HTTP services that receives simple events like an id, timestamp, and processor name, then in your flow you could put InvokeHttp processors wherever you want to report status to your service. Then your UI would use the status events in it's own DB or wherever you store them.